Incorporating Checkbox to lines of code rather than Cell value
I've currently got a checkbox in A17 that i want to replace the function of M9 value 0/1.
How do i effectively implement this?
  If Target.Address = "$M$9" Then
  If Target.Value > 0 Then
               If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
               Rows("20:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
            Else
                Rows("20:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
       Else
            If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
               Rows("20:22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
            Else
                Rows("20:22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
           End If
       End If
   End If


I've tried lines as:
If Target.Address = "Check Box 8" Then If Target.Value = True Then
etc
Didn't quite work.. Where can i tell exactly What the check box needs to be referred to? And what would you do to make a checked box show rows and unchecked hide them..?

What kind of check box do you use? An ActiveX type or Form one?

You shouldn't use Activesheet in a worksheet event module, unless you really mean that - if for example a change gets made to the sheet via code while some other sheet is active, you will get unwanted outcomes...  Use Me instead of ActiveSheet

@FaneDuru Honestly didn't know there were two, but i see i'm using form one atm.

Then, I would recommend you to use ActiveX controls. They are able to do more than Form type, they are easier to be customized as you need...

Since you did not answer my clarification question, I prepared codes for both cases, respectively:

The case of ActiveX combo box, the simplest one:

You need to double click it and paste the next code overwriting its Click event:
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click() 'of course, you must adapt the real check box name (maybe, CheckBox8_Click)
  Dim HdRows As Range
  Set HdRows = Me.rows("20:22")
  If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
     If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
        Me.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
         HdRows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Me.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
     Else
        HdRows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
     End If
  Else
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
        Me.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
         HdRows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Me.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
     Else
        HdRows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If
  End If
End Sub


If the involved check box is Form type (most probably, looking to its name containing spaces), you need to use the next solution:

a. Copy the next code in a Standard module:
Sub hideRows()
 Const myChkb As String = "Check Box 8" 'use here the check box REAL name
 If Application.Caller = myChkb Then
    Dim ws As Worksheet, chkName As String, chkB As CheckBox, HdRows As Range
    chkName = myChkb
    Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set HdRows = ws.rows("20:22")
    Set chkB = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(chkName)
    If chkB.Value = 1 Then
        If ws.ProtectContents Then
           ws.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
            HdRows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
           ws.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
        Else
           HdRows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
     Else
       If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
           ws.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
            HdRows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
           ws.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
        Else
           HdRows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
 End If
End Sub

b. Right click on the combo box and from the context menu choose Assign Macro...
Select hideRows (the one copied above) and press OK.
Now, you can play with checking - unchecking the respective check box and see the rows to be hidden - visible.
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

If you want to see whether the checkbox is checked or not;
Sub Test()
    Dim myCheckBox As Shape
    
    Set myCheckBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 8")
    
    If myCheckBox.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "CheckBox is checked"
    Else
        MsgBox "CheckBox is NOT checked"
    End If
End Sub

Note: "Check Box 8" is NOT an ActiveX element, it is a "Form Control" and the code assumes that, "Check Box 8" is on the active page. If not, use the relevant sheet name.
You can place your own code within the IF-Else block depending on the "state" of the check box whether it is checked or not.
